# What's the most idiomatic approach to multi-index collections in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In C++ and other languages, add-on libraries implement a multi-index container, e.g. [Boost.Multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).  That is, a collection that stores one type of value but maintains multiple different indices over those values.  These indices provide for different access methods and sorting behaviors, e.g. map, multimap, set, multiset, array, etc.  Run-time complexity of the multi-index container is generally the sum of the individual indices' complexities.

Is there an equivalent for Haskell or do people compose their own?  Specifically, what is the most idiomatic way to implement a collection of type T with both a set-type of index (T is an instance of `Ord`) as well as a map-type of index (assume that a key value of type K could be provided for each T, either explicitly or via a function `T -> K`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the trivial case where every element has a unique key that's always available, you can just use a `Map` and extract the key to look up an element. In the slightly less  trivial case where each value merely *has* a key available, a simple solution it would be something like `Map K (Set T)`. Looking up an element directly would then involve first extracting the key, indexing the `Map` to find the set of elements that share that key, then looking up the one you want.

For the most part, if something can be done straightforwardly in the above fashion (simple transformation and nesting), it probably makes sense to do it that way. However, none of this generalizes well to, e.g., multiple independent keys or keys that may not be available, for obvious reasons.

Beyond that, I'm not aware of any widely-used standard implementations. Some examples do exist, for example [IxSet from happstack](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-ixset) seems to roughly fit the bill. I suspect one-size-kinda-fits-most solutions here are liable to have a poor benefit/complexity ratio, so people tend to just roll their own to suit specific needs.

Intuitively, this seems like a problem that might work better not as a single implementation, but rather a collection of primitives that could be composed more flexibly than `Data.Map` allows, to create ad-hoc specialized structures. But that's not really helpful for short-term needs.

Answer (score 7):

I just uploaded IxSet to hackage this morning,

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ixset

ixset provides sets which have multiple indexes.

ixset has been around for a long time as happstack-ixset. This version removes the dependencies on anything happstack specific, and is the new official version of IxSet.

Another option would be kdtree:

darcs get http://darcs.monoid.at/kdtree

kdtree aims to improve on IxSet by offering greater type-safety and better time and space usage. The current version seems to do well on all three of those aspects -- but it is not yet ready for prime time. Additional contributors would be highly welcomed.

Comment: The kdtree link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

For this specific question, you can use a [Bimap](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bimap/0.2.4/doc/html/Data-Bimap.html). In general, though, I'm not aware of any common class for multimaps or multiply-indexed containers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the simplest way to do this is simply with Data.Map. Although it is designed to use single indices, when you insert the same element multiple times, most compilers (certainly GHC) will make the values place to the same place. A separate implementation of a multimap wouldn't be that efficient, as you want to find elements based on their index, so you cannot naively associate each element with multiple indices - say `[([key], value)]` - as this would be very inefficient.

However, I have not looked at the Boost implementations of Multimaps to see, definitively, if there is an optimized way of doing so.

Comment: What exactly does "Although it is designed to use single indices, when you insert the same element multiple times, most compilers (certainly GHC) will make the values place to the same place." mean?

Comment: If you insert the same item into a Map 5 times, it will not take five times as much space as inserting it once, because internally, all five values are pointers to the same place.

Answer (score 2):

Have I got the problem straight? Both T and K have an order. There is a function key :: T -> K but it is not *order-preserving*. It is desired to manage a collection of Ts, indexed (for rapid access) both by the T order and the K order. More generally, one might want a collection of T elements indexed by a bunch of orders key1 :: T -> K1, .. keyn :: T -> Kn, and it so happens that here key1 = id. Is that the picture?

I think I agree with gereeter's suggestion that the basis for a solution is just to maintiain in sync a bunch of (Map K1 T, .. Map Kn T). Inserting a key-value pair in a map duplicates neither the key nor the value, allocating only the extra heap required to make a new entry in the right place in the index. Inserting the same value, suitably keyed, in multiple indices should not break sharing (even if one of the keys *is* the value). It is worth wrapping the structure in an API which ensures that any subsequent modifications to the value are computed once and shared, rather than recomputed for each entry in an index.

Bottom line: it should be possible to maintain multiple maps, ensuring that the values are shared, even though the key-orders are separate.

Comment: Complicating the implementation is that arbitrary projection functions may not simply amputate fragments of the value but calculate keys from it, there may be relationships between the keys that matter beyond their use as indices, approximate matches using multiple keys may be useful, clumsy types for the composite structure to include the valid keys... my experience is that needing a multi-key map with no further structure is somewhat rare, and APIs for such can easily interfere with adding such structure.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your helpful answers.  I ended up rolling my own (and thanks Conor for the warning re: sharing).  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some uber-cool Haskell library.  I'm still in the phase of having my mind blown daily...